# C++ code documenting: doxygen vs built into vc++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, doxygen, code-documentation

Does anyone use built into VC help generating system (/Doc - compiler option) .
Adv/dis in a comparing with Doxygen (excluding platform specific)? 
Similar option in C# compiler can raise a warnings in case of undocumented items found in the code. but didn't find this for C++ version. is this really possible?

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen has many additional features:

1. Can generate documentation in various formats (html, xml (see later), info, latex, ...)
2. Generates easy to use index and navigation.
3. Formatting is pretty advanced, you can use lists, group the methods, etc.
4. Can generate caller/callee graphs
5. Generates inheritance and dependency graphs
6. Generates dependency graphs for the namespaces
7. Generates xml output which is easily parseable and may be used for further processing.

... well, there are few more of them but these are quite significant ones which could help you with not only document but also analyzing the project.